# MacBook Pro USB disabled and dead battery. What to do?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, battery

I was constantly getting a notification that USB ports had been disabled due to an accessory using too much power. Most of the time there was nothing plugged in when I received the notification. So, in an attempt to fix this problem I reset the SCM(option-command-power while off), but that really screwed everything up. I was never able to boot up fully again. It would ask for password, but never get passed that. Once I was able to successfully boot in safe mode.  The biggest problem is that after resetting the SCM it never again accepted a charge. I’m thinking that the USB ports stayed disabled. Now, my battery is dead and I can’t charge it to even try fixing it.  Any ideas? I’m at a loss. Thanks

Edit: Assuming it is not a hardware problem (which it seems like it is), are there any ideas on how to get the battery charged to at least attempt to work on it?

Comment: Sounds like hardware error. I would take it in for repairs.

Comment: Try resetting the SMC again, but if things get *worse* after an SMC reset, it's most likely the logic board.

Comment: I did do a hardware test(holding D down on boot up) before resetting SCM to see if it would say anything about USB issues. Everything checked out ok in that test.

Comment: Not being able to charge is a hardware issue.  It *must* go in for service as there is nothing you can do to overcome this.

Comment: Try resetting the PRAM. It's worth a shot too. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063